# SQL database design scenario

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out what the best table design is for my use case scenario.

I have a table that stores order information called `OrderHeader`. This table has a column called order `OrdStatus`.

The user can change order status when updating the order. However, the user also requires to store extra information when order status is set to cancelled. Thus, i created another table called `CancelledOrder`

So the way i have designed the database is as follows:

[image]

So now i am wondering if this is the correct way to design my database to suit this particular requirement. I am asking this question as i keep running into this situation from time to time.

Comment: is it really necessary to create a new table when the order is cancelled? What is user deletes the order

Comment: The user cannot delete the order, he can only update the order status. For example, open=>processing=>delivered=>cancelled. The User interface does not have the functionality to delete the order.

Comment: what does ordStatus refer in your table?

Comment: Also i thought it would be redundant to keep the cancelled order information in the same table, as it only applies when order status is set to cancelled. What do you think?

Comment: It refers to the order status ID

Comment: You had not to create a table for every order status with specific field, put every fields in the same table and handle it in application layer

Comment: So your are saying its is okay to have empty columns in my OrderHeader table, meaning when the OrderStatus is not cancelled i will have three columns with no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the some status field(apart from what you having), which represents the state of order whether it is in Pending State/Cancelled or Shipped. It will be redundant to create one more table just for cancelled order.Though you can have other child table to represents items in your order.
Even the large e commerce framework also support single table(have many child table) having all types of order.
Until you don't have very specific requirement don't go for extra table.
**Just for reference** https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.database.doc/database/orders.htm
Just have a look and see can you make most of it

Comment: @cosmos you can use this as reference. but do not over complicate it

Comment: Indeed, the application is very simple. So basically, i am going to have to add three extra columns to my main OrderHeader table: 1. DateCancelled. 2. CancelComment. 3. CancelledBy

Comment: Not really convinced. But i appreciate the input and help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could see Normalization of databases for it (http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/).

Design the tables of a database isn't a simple work, there is multiple implications.

The correct answer to your questions is provided by the process of normalization.